# Copy files with start and end date specified

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch script to copy a directory with files in it

xcopy "C:\Test" "D:\Test" /D/E/C/R/I/K/Y

But I neet the script which would copy only those files older than specified date&time1 and newer than specified date&time2. for example, there should be file created between 10.00 am 12.01.2012 and 2.00 pm 13.01.2012. The directory structure should remain the same as the original one. 
The script should work under Windows Server 2003.

Comment: It give me pains to think about coding that in a .bat (if it can be done). I'd go Perl (or mingw/cygwin). Anyway, I wonder if this question should be migrated to SO

Comment: [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51054)